# Sefer "Bilvavi Mishkan Evneh" on "Mesillas Yeasharim"

Tags: jewish-books, mussar-ethics, ramchal

There is a *Sefer* called *Bilvavi Mishkan Evneh* by R' Itamar Shwartz on *Mesillas Yesharim.* It happens to be out of print , but would anyone know where I could find it?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Consider learning more about the site with the following brief [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

Try this link...
[http://www.bilvavi.net/files/בלבבי.מסילת.ישרים.חלק.א.ב.pdf](http://www.bilvavi.net/files/%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%91%D7%99.%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA.%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D.%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7.%D7%90.%D7%91.pdf)

Comment: Much of which is available in unofficial English translation at http://www.bilvavi.net/sugya/mesillas (chapter by chapter).